# App Engine Flexible Golang can not access Datastore after successful deployment

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am using GAE Golang (runtime: go env: flex). 
Deployed with `gcloud beta app deploy app.yaml --project xxxx`. Since this morning, our code can no longer access datastore.

I am getting the following error when try to connect to datastore:

"service bridge HTTP failed: Post http://appengine.googleapis.internal:10001/rpc_http: dial tcp: lookup appengine.googleapis.internal on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host"

Do you experience the same issue? Is there any workaround?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Solved, it was my bad. I was still using datastore client from "google.golang.org/appengine/datastore" instead of "cloud.google.com/go/datastore".